# How to use Netbeans Design IDE function

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I started using the JFrame "designer" under Netbeans, but I have no clue how to add actual functions to the buttons I create.  I'm trying to make a program where you click a button, and it opens whatever program you just selected.  (For example, you hit the button that says "Interent" and it opens chrome/firefox)
I have made the GUI, but I don't know how to add code to the buttons.

Comment: In the form designer, double click the button you want to add an action to, it should generate the `actionPerformed` code for you

Comment: Thank you a lot!  Works perfectly... Now I actually have to figure out the code I want to do.. Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form editor enabled, select the element you want to attach events to.  In the control's Properties sheet, click "Events" to see list of events that are directly available.

For things like buttons, you can simply double click them and Netbeans will automatically generate `actionPerformed` code for you.

This won't help in all cases (such as text fields, where the `Document` has it's owner listeners), in cases like these, you're going to have to understand how event listeners work.

[image]